Demolishing Concrete Patio that Protects Foundation and Door Threshold
Past questions have considered the general case of removing a patio that adjoins to a foundation, but I was hoping to show a few photos of my job and see if any specific advice applies here. My house is a brick facade on a basement concrete foundation, shown in the first picture.

The left half of the picture shows the patio, which is 2 steps, the first 4" and the second 6". The top 6" section of the patio thus adjoins brick, rather than the concrete foundation, and there appears to be some kind of sealant here:

The thing that really gives me pause is that the concrete threshold of a big sliding door seems to be part of the patio pour—I don't see a seam here:

So I'm worried about damaging the threshold when I go to remove that section of the patio. I was thinking about using a jackhammer + hand tools, but now I'm thinking...do I need a saw? Anything else here to think about?

Pictures from a bit farther away would give a better idea of what you have there.  Generally from your description I see a concrete saw in your future.

Why must the patio be removed?  Perhaps there is a work around.

Here's what I ended up going with: I used a concrete saw (as mentioned by @RMDman) to cut a nice clean section around the door (which will function as a step). I then broke away the remaining concrete, including the portion that had a joint with the brick facade. I think it was a good compromise! The saw rental was about $75 for 4 hours, from Home Depot.
